# Is it possible to display a progressbar dialog before setContentView() called in android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application an activity takes more than 10 seconds to load (it contains a number of TextViews with lengthy text values), now I want to show a progress bar dialog window during the Activity loading? Is it possible by using 'AsyncTask'? if possible then how can I pause the UI thread until AsyncTask to complete,.When I tries to show a dialog before setContentView() call I got an error like 
**android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application**

Comment: wow, how many textviews do you have in your layout to make it load 10 seconds!?

Comment: trying to show a dialog before setContentView() will give you this sort of error only.Show after it and dismiss after setting textview

Comment: actually it is a 'report' page  thats why I  need all textviews in a single activity

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866846/show-a-progress-bar-when-an-activity-is-loading> This link will helps you.

Comment: The above link might be helps you better if no then i will helps further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` and `Viewswitcher` to switch between two layouts(each layout is a view).First set your `contentView` and in `onPostExecute`(after loading) switch your layouts.
Edit:
For more details,see [this page](http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/android_dont_overlook_viewswitcher/).