# Android - what does requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) do?

Tags: android, window, android-progressbar

Pretty much in in the title.

Have seen this around and after a bit of searching can't seem to find out what it actually does or what indeterminate progress is.

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)`

It's used for example by [RoboSpice samples](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/release/robospice-sample-core-fragment/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/basic/fragment/MainActivity.java).

Comment: It is used for progress bar, see the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866846/show-a-progress-bar-when-an-activity-is-loading

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Update: Currently this feature is deprecated and not supported on current devices,
check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS).

Original answer:

Simply rotating circle in top right corner in Actionbar which represent some background action.

[image]

Screenshot is from [Sherlock Actionbar demos](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html).